# Java - Mobile apps cross platform

Tags: android, java, ios, cross-platform, eclipse

I need a free framework that allows to code apps for the latest Mobile OS.

I prefer to use Eclipse IDE.

Apps should run on all Mobile OS (IOS 7+, Android KitKat+, Windows Phone).

I'd like to use Spring and MySql/SqlLite.

Which one is the best to code mobile apps cross-platform in java?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. "The best" is far to subjective with almost no criteria given – and almost no criteria also means it's far too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel’s Multi-OS Engine is a technology that enables developers using their Java expertise to develop native mobile applications for iOS and Android on Windows and/or OS X development host machines without compromising the native look, feel and performance. This technology is a stand-alone plug-in that can be integrated into Android Studio.

It's free and let's you write code and create UI easily in Android Studio. You can generate API for 3rd party libraries in Java etc.

More details and the download link are here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/multi-os-engine

Answer (score 0):

[Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) (of which I am a co-founder) allows just that. You write your app in Java and it will work across all mobile OS's (iOS, Android, Windows etc.). I'm obviously biased but its free to begin with and open source so your can try it and see if you love it. Codename One works well in Eclipse as well as NetBeans and IntelliJ.

Other options include Xamrin/RoboVM where you can write the app in C#/Java but would need to adapt the UI code (and possibly additional code) for every OS. RoboVM supported Eclipse in the past but I think they moved to focus on their own IDE which I think is based on IntelliJ (might be wrong here).

There is also PhoneGap/Cordova which is HTML5 based, you can probably use Eclipse for that too.